# How does a view obtain data using a view model and Network API

Tags: api, swiftui, protocols, viewmodel, combine

I'm trying to fetch some data with this helper file:
https://gist.github.com/jbfbell/e011c5e4c3869584723d79927b7c4b68

Here's a snippet of the important code:

**Class**

```
/// Base class for requests to the Alpha Vantage Stock Data API.  Intended to be subclasssed, but can
/// be used directly if library does not support a new api.
class AlphaVantageRequest : ApiRequest {

    private static let alphaApi = AlphaVantageRestApi()
    let method = "GET"
    let path = ""
    let queryStringParameters : Array<URLQueryItem>
    let api : RestApi = AlphaVantageRequest.alphaApi

    var responseJSON : [String : Any]? {
        didSet {
            if let results = responseJSON {
            print(results)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Extension ApiRequest**

```
    /// Makes asynchronous call to fetch response from server, stores response on self
    ///
    /// - Returns: self to allow for chained method calls
    public func callApi() -> ApiRequest {
        guard let apiRequest = createRequest() else {
            print("No Request to make")
            return self
        }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: apiRequest) {(data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
            print("Error Reaching API, \(String(describing: apiRequest.url))")
            return
            }
            self.receiveResponse(data)
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        return self
    }
```

My goal is to fetch the data from **responseJSON** after the data of the url request is loaded.

My ViewModel currently looks like this:

```
class CompanyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var companyOverviewRequest: ApiRequest? {
        didSet {
            if let response = companyOverviewRequest?.responseJSON {
                print(response)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var searchEndpoint: SearchEndpoint
    
    init(companyOverviewRequest: AlphaVantageRequest? = nil,
         searchEndpoint: SearchEndpoint) {
        
        self.companyOverviewRequest = CompanyOverviewRequest(symbol: searchEndpoint.symbol)
    }
    
    
    func fetchCompanyOverview() {
        
        guard let request = self.companyOverviewRequest?.callApi() else { return }
        self.companyOverviewRequest = request

    }
    
}
```

So in my ViewModel the didSet gets called once but not when it should store the data. The results of **AlphaVantageRequest** always prints out properly, but not in my ViewModel. How can I achieve to have the loaded data also in my ViewModel?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use your own "API" layer using Combine, which is just a thin wrapper around URLSession. You will find plenty of examples which implement fetching, decoding and error handling in 5 lines of code. No need to use this elaborated API layer which also has a couple sever flaws.

Comment: A better title for you question would be "How does a view obtain data using a view model and Network API, also adding a tag "combine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a view model which is an ObservableObject, your view wants to observe *published* properties, usually a `viewState` (MVVM terminology):

```
class CompanyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum ViewState {
        case undefined
        case value(Company)
    }
    @Published var viewState: ViewState = .undefined
```

`viewState` completely describes how your view will be rendered. Note, that it can be `undefined` - which your view should be able to handle.
Adding a `loading(Company?)` case would also be a good idea. Your view can then render a loading indicator. Note that loading also provides an optional company value. You can then render a "refresh", in which case you already have a company value while also drawing a loading indicator.

In order to fetch some data from an endpoint, you may use the following abstraction:

```
public protocol HTTPClient: class {
    func publisher(for request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<HTTPResponse, Swift.Error>
}
```

This can be implemented by a simple wrapper around URLSession with 5 lines of code. A conforming type may however do much more: it may handle authentication, authorization, it may retry requests, refresh access tokens, or present user interfaces where the user needs to authenticate, etc. This simple protocol is sufficient for all this.

So, how does your ViewModel get the data?

It makes sense to introduce another abstraction: "UseCase" which performs this task, and not let the view model directly use the HTTP client.
A "use case" is simply an object that performs a task, taking an input and producing an output or error. You can name it how you want, "DataProvider", "ContentProvider" or something like this. "Use Case" is a well known term, though.
Conceptually, it has a similar API as an HTTP client, but semantically it sits on a higher level:

```
public protocol UseCase {
    associatedtype Input: Encodable
    associatedtype Output: Decodable
    associatedtype Error

    func callAsFunction(with input: Input) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Error>
}
```

Lets create us a "GetCompany" use case:

```
struct Company: Codable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
}

struct GetCompanyUseCase: UseCase {
    typealias Input = Int
    typealias Output = Company
    typealias Error = Swift.Error

    private let httpClient: HTTPClient

    init(httpClient: HTTPClient) {
        self.httpClient = httpClient
    }

    func callAsFunction(with id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Company, Swift.Error> {
        let request = composeURLRequest(input: id)
        return httpClient.publisher(for: request)
            .tryMap { httpResponse in
                switch httpResponse {
                case .success(_, let data):
                    return data
                default:
                    throw "invalid status code"
                }
            }
            .decode(type: Company.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .map { $0 } // no-op, usually you receive a "DTO.Company" value and transform it into your Company type.
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private func composeURLRequest(input: Int) -> URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.my.com/companies?id=\(input)")!
        return URLRequest(url: url)
    }
}
```

So, this Use Case clearly accesses our HTTP client. We can implement this accessing CoreData, or read from file, or using a mock, etc. The API is always the same, and the view model does not care. The beauty here is, you can switch it out and swap in another one, the view model still works and also your view. (In order to make this really cool, you would create a `AnyUseCase` generic type, which is very easy, and here you have your dependency injection).

Now lets see how the view model may look like and how it uses the Use Case:

```
class CompanyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum ViewState {
        case undefined
        case value(Company)
    }
    @Published var viewState: ViewState = .undefined

    let getCompany: GetCompanyUseCase
    var getCompanyCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init(getCompany: GetCompanyUseCase) {
        self.getCompany = getCompany
    }

    func load() {
        self.getCompanyCancellable =
        self.getCompany(with: 1)
            .sink { (completion) in
                print(completion)
            } receiveValue: { (company) in
                self.viewState = .value(company)
                print("company set to: \(company)")
            }
    }
}
```

The `load` function triggers the use case, which calls the underlying http client to load the company data.

When the UseCase returns a company, it will be assigned the view state. Observers (the view, or ViewController) will get notified about the change and can preform an update.

You can experiment with code in playground. Here are the missing peaces:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

extension String: Swift.Error {}

public enum HTTPResponse {
    case information(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
    case success(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
    case redirect(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
    case clientError(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
    case serverError(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
    case custom(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
}

class MockHTTPClient: HTTPClient {
    func publisher(for request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<HTTPResponse, Swift.Error> {
        let json = #"{"id": 1, "name": "Some Corporation"}"#.data(using: .utf8)!
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.my.com/companies")!
        let httpUrlResponse = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)!
        let response: HTTPResponse = .success(response: httpUrlResponse, data: json)
        return Just(response)
            .mapError { _ in "no error" }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Assemble:

```
let httpClient = MockHTTPClient()
let getCompany = GetCompany(httpClient: httpClient)
let viewModel = CompanyViewModel(getCompany: getCompany)
viewModel.load()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I accomplished now to fetch the data. The implementation of the viewState was quite different to that, what I did before in SwiftUI. But it is a great way to render the view differently.

Comment: SwiftUI Views actually always observe their view state. The above is just a more clear separation of SwiftUI Views and a view model. It's more structured and aims for defining a convention for how you would architecture your app. You can use this approach in UIKit as well: import Combine in a ViewController and observe the view state, or - if you don't want to use Combine in your ViewControllers, use an "Adapter" that converts an observing view state into a "Presenter" which "pushes" a view state to the view, like `presenter.view.updateModel(viewState)`.

Comment: Is it possible to have two viewStates with data? I made a chained request with 4 requests in total. Two of the requests take very long (its stock market data with daily points over 20 years). For the user experience it would be much better if I could refresh the view, when the first two requests are done, store them in the viewState and wait then for the next two requests. I thought of having two different ViewModels and combine the results in a top-level ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, that's possible in several ways: UseCase returns a "Publisher", which basically means, it can yield more than one value and the value could possibly incrementally update. Note that a publisher (per design) can yield values at any time, even when there is no user action. Or, you use several "@published" values in your view model, each being responsible for defining the state for rendering a certain "child view" of your View. Hint: in a first attempt, make it as simple as possible: view model waits till the content data is complete, then updates the view state.